# "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" When locking screen

Tags: android, locking, android-activity

I'm not sure if this always happened within my application and just now that I realized that.

I have an activity that is always in Landscape Mode I have a thread to read messages from a socket runnin too.

For some reason when I lock my screen using my phone locking button I got a "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo". The activity that triggers the error is the same activity that was running when I locked the screen.

It looks like the activity is recreating itself when I lock the screen.

I'm out of ideas on how to figure a solution for this... first I thought it had something to the WakeLock that I putted inside the activities code but after removal of that snippet i

Comment: Put log outputs in the overrides of onDestroy, onCreate, and any other function you think might be going off, then see if they are being called when you lock the screen. This will help you narrow down the problem

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried to add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to my activity declaration on the Manifest file and now the error is not happening anymore.

I don't know if there is another solution for this but this worked for me.